# Are these tags synonymous?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-synonyms

I came across these tags. Are these tags synonymous?

- [spanish-language](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spanish-language)
- [language-processing](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-processing)
- [natural-language](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language)
- [natural-language-processing](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language-processing)

The Spanish language tag is not synonymous, but I don't find what purpose it serves.

Also I think these time should be a subset of optimization:

- [optimization](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)
- [time](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re: The 3 NLP tags

This has been on my radar for a little while.  I've just briefly re-reviewed the questions for these three tags and see no reason not to merge.

**If anyone has any reason these tags should not be merged, speak now or forever hold your peace**

---

Re: "spanish-language" tag

This is one I decided to test out, related to a question asking for both English and Spanish language resources.  Spanish is the #2 language in the US, so it might be worthwhile to see if this tag gets any additional use.  (If not, we can always delete.)

---

Re: "time" tag

I've replaced the "time" tag with a new "time-complexity" tag on this question: [Neural networks efficiently solve traveling salesmen problems?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/2874/neural-networks-efficiently-solve-traveling-salesmen-problems)

[This question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/184/1671), however, seems to be about automata learning the concept of time.  Based on a linked research paper, I've tentatively updated the "time" tag to refer to perceptual time.